# Laravel produces large file size php_error.log (multiple gigabyte)

Tags: laravel

My setup:

- Laravel 5.5-dev (the same problem appears also with Laravel 5.4)
- MAMP PRO (4.1.1)

  - PHP version 7.1.1
  - MySQL version 5.6.35

A use case to provoke an error situation would be for example:

```
Route::geet('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});
```

This produces for example the following php_error.log: http://filehorst.de/d/bovaxAyb
(It took about 5 seconds to produce this log file.)

First lines of the log file:

```
[03-Jul-2017 05:35:37 UTC] PHP Warning:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Internal error: Failed to retrieve the default value in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/projects/laravel/lfs54/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Caster/ReflectionCaster.php:259
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/projects/laravel/lfs54/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Caster/ReflectionCaster.php(259): ReflectionParameter->getDefaultValue()
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/projects/laravel/lfs54/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Caster/ReflectionCaster.php(46): Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Caster\ReflectionCaster::castParameter(Object(ReflectionParameter), Array, Object(Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\Stub), true)
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/projects/laravel/lfs54/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Cloner/AbstractCloner.php(277): Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Caster\ReflectionCaster::castClosure(Object(ReflectionFunction), Array, Object(Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\Stub), false, 1)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/projects/laravel/lfs54/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/C in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/projects/laravel/lfs54/vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Caster/ReflectionCaster.php on line 259
[03-Jul-2017 05:35:37 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[03-Jul-2017 05:35:37 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/projects/laravel/lfs54/public/index.php:0
[03-Jul-2017 05:35:37 UTC] PHP   2. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle($request = class Illuminate\Http\Request { protected $json = NULL; protected $convertedFiles = NULL; protected $userResolver = NULL; protected $routeResolver = NULL; public $attributes = class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag { protected $parameters = array () }; public $request = class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag { protected $parameters = array () }; public $query = class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag { protected $parameters = array () }; public $server = class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag { protected $parameters = array ('HTTP_HOST' => 'lfs54.dev', 'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'keep-alive', 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => 'max-age=0', 'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS' => '1', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36', 'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip, deflate', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ru;q=0.2', 'HTTP_COOKIE' => 'XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjFaZkRiSnV1R0ROS3ZaZ1NhRSt1Z2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibks2VUI2OHZ6QzAxOHhEVWk1QjMzUjJwUzB0UGFZSXlLN1k4NmRhME9QYm9ZXC8xdWxlaVZNOU9cL3prM0VVSkMrN0J1N1czYW5vZHZ1WEY0RTdOWnNPQT09IiwibWFjIjoiMmFiMmUxOWJkMDhjZmVhYWIxMGIyYzNmYWIzNTAwMTRhY2RhY2M3NGM4MGUzNzM2OTFkOTliYmI3ODcwN2QzMiJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkFhcDU3cE9OUWlKaDhYQXBJTDlTbXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiakE4NlZqcVBcL2JVK0RUaGNOUitoVUxMdW00WWdwR091SjNrT3NqcjVBMHNhZ202bG9MaGhFanlMVlUxQVZPOFJiQ0dxNmhxcGtpcHg1SGk4OW5WalwvZz09IiwibWFjIjoiZWViYjM4NTdkZDlmMGJlZGEwYzQwODRlYTE3NjY0YzAwNjZiYzQ2YmE4OGI2ODMxM2MzMjQ2NWRhNTM5MzYzZSJ9', 'PATH' => '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin', 'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => '', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'Apache', 'SERVER_NAME' => 'lfs54.dev', 'SERVER_ADDR' => '::1', 'SERVER_PORT' => '80', 'REMOTE_ADDR' => '::1', 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/projects/laravel/lfs54/public', 'SERVER_ADMIN' => 'you@example.com', 'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/projects/laravel/lfs54/public/index.php', 'REMOTE_PORT' => '59421', 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => 'CGI/1.1', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1', 'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET', 'QUERY_STRING' => '', 'REQUEST_URI' => '/', 'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/index.php', 'PHP_SELF' => '/index.php', 'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => 1499060129.5, 'REQUEST_TIME' => 1499060129, 'argv' => array (), 'argc' => 0) }; public $files = class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag { protected $parameters = array () }; public $cookies = class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag { protected $parameters = array ('XSRF-TOKEN' => 'eyJpdiI6IjFaZkRiSnV1R0ROS3ZaZ1NhRSt1Z2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibks2VUI2OHZ6QzAxOHhEVWk1QjMzUjJwUzB0UGFZSXlLN1k4NmRhME9QYm9ZXC8xdWxlaVZNOU9cL3prM0VVSkMrN0J1N1czYW5vZHZ1WEY0RTdOWnNPQT09IiwibWFjIjoiMmFiMmUxOWJkMDhjZmVhYWIxMGIyYzNmYWIzNTAwMTRhY2RhY2M3NGM4MGUzNzM2OTFkOTliYmI3ODcwN2QzMiJ9', 'laravel_session' => 'eyJpdiI6IkFhcDU3cE9OUWlKaDhYQXBJTDlTbXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiakE4NlZqcVBcL2JVK0RUaGNOUitoVUxMdW00WWdwR091SjNrT3NqcjVBMHNhZ202bG9MaGhFanlMVlUxQVZPOFJiQ0dxNmhxcGtpcHg1SGk4OW5WalwvZz09IiwibWFjIjoiZWViYjM4NTdkZDlmMGJlZGEwYzQwODRlYTE3NjY0YzAwNjZiYzQ2YmE4OGI2ODMxM2MzMjQ2NWRhNTM5MzYzZSJ9') }; public $headers = class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag { protected $headers = array ('host' => array (0 => 'lfs54.dev'), 'connection' => array (0 => 'keep-alive'), 'cache-control' => array (0 => 'max-age=0'), 'upgrade-insecure-requests' => array (0 => '1'), 'user-agent' => array (0 => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'), 'accept' => array (0 => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8'), 'accept-encoding' => array (0 => 'gzip, deflate'), 'accept-language' => array (0 => 'de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ru;q=0.2'), 'cookie' => array (0 => 'XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjFaZkRiSnV1R0ROS3ZaZ1NhRSt1Z2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibks2VUI2OHZ6QzAxOHhEVWk1QjMzUjJwUzB0UGFZSXlLN1k4NmRhME9QYm9ZXC8xdWxlaVZNOU9cL3prM0VVSkMrN0J1N1czYW5vZHZ1WEY0RTdOWnNPQT09IiwibWFjIjoiMmFiMmUxOWJkMDhjZmVhYWIxMGIyYzNmYWIzNTAwMTRhY2RhY2M3NGM4MGUzNzM2OTFkOTliYmI3ODcwN2QzMiJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkFhcDU3cE9OUWlKaDhYQXBJTDlTbXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiakE4NlZqcVBcL2JVK0RUaGNOUitoVUxMdW00WWdwR091SjNrT3NqcjVBMHNhZ202bG9MaGhFanlMVlUxQVZPOFJiQ0dxNmhxcGtpcHg1SGk4OW5WalwvZz09IiwibWFjIjoiZWViYjM4NTdkZDlmMGJlZGEwYzQwODRlYTE3NjY0YzAwNjZiYzQ2YmE4OGI2ODMxM2MzMjQ2NWRhNTM5MzYzZSJ9')); protected $cacheControl = array ('max-age' => '0') }; protected $content = NULL; protected $languages = NULL; protected $charsets = NULL; protected $encodings = NULL; protected $acceptableContentTypes = array (0 => 'text/html', 1 => 'application/xhtml+xml', 2 => 'image/webp', 3 => 'image/apng', 4 => 'application/xml', 5 => '*/*'); protected $pathInfo = NULL; protected $requestUri = NULL; protected $baseUrl = NULL; protected $basePath = NULL; protected $method = NULL; protected $format = NULL; protected $session = NULL; protected $locale = NULL; protected $defaultLocale = 'en'; private ${Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request}:isHostValid = TRUE; private ${Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request}:isClientIpsValid = TRUE; private ${Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request}:isForwardedValid = TRUE }) /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/projects/laravel/lfs54/public/index.php:55
[03-Jul-2017 05:35:37 UTC] PHP   3. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->renderException($request = class Illuminate\Http\Request { protected $json = NULL; protected $convertedFiles = NULL; protected $userResolver = NULL; protected $routeResolver = NULL; public $attributes = class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag { protected $parameters = array () }; public $request = class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag { protected $parameters = array () }; public $query = class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag { protected $parameters = array () }; public $server = class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag { protected $parameters = array ('HTTP_HOST' => 'lfs54.dev', 'HTTP_CONNECTION' => 'keep-alive', 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => 'max-age=0', 'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS' => '1', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36', 'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => 'gzip, deflate', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => 'de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ru;q=0.2', 'HTTP_COOKIE' => 'XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjFaZkRiSnV1R0ROS3ZaZ1NhRSt1Z2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibks2VUI2OHZ6QzAxOHhEVWk1QjMzUjJwUzB0UGFZSXlLN1k4NmRhME9QYm9ZXC8xdWxlaVZNOU9cL3prM0VVSkMrN0J1N1czYW5vZHZ1WEY0RTdOWnNPQT09IiwibWFjIjoiMmFiMmUxOWJkMDhjZmVhYWIxMGIyYzNmYWIzNTAwMTRhY2RhY2M3NGM4MGUzNzM2OTFkOTliYmI3ODcwN2QzMiJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkFhcDU3cE9OUWlKaDhYQXBJTDlTbXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiakE4NlZqcVBcL2JVK0RUaGNOUitoVUxMdW00WWdwR091SjNrT3NqcjVBMHNhZ202bG9MaGhFanlMVlUxQVZPOFJiQ0dxNmhxcGtpcHg1SGk4OW5WalwvZz09IiwibWFjIjoiZWViYjM4NTdkZDlmMGJlZGEwYzQwODRlYTE3NjY0YzAwNjZiYzQ2YmE4OGI2ODMxM2MzMjQ2NWRhNTM5MzYzZSJ9', 'PATH' => '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin', 'SERVER_SIGNATURE' => '', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'Apache', 'SERVER_NAME' => 'lfs54.dev', 'SERVER_ADDR' => '::1', 'SERVER_PORT' => '80', 'REMOTE_ADDR' => '::1', 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/projects/laravel/lfs54/public', 'SERVER_ADMIN' => 'you@example.com', 'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/projects/laravel/lfs54/public/index.php', 'REMOTE_PORT' => '59421', 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => 'CGI/1.1', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1', 'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET', 'QUERY_STRING' => '', 'REQUEST_URI' => '/', 'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/index.php', 'PHP_SELF' => '/index.php', 'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => 1499060129.5, 'REQUEST_TIME' => 1499060129, 'argv' => array (), 'argc' => 0) }; public $files = class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag { protected $parameters = array () }; public $cookies = class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag { protected $parameters = array ('XSRF-TOKEN' => 'eyJpdiI6IjFaZkRiSnV1R0ROS3ZaZ1NhRSt1Z2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibks2VUI2OHZ6QzAxOHhEVWk1QjMzUjJwUzB0UGFZSXlLN1k4NmRhME9QYm9ZXC8xdWxlaVZNOU9cL3prM0VVSkMrN0J1N1czYW5vZHZ1WEY0RTdOWnNPQT09IiwibWFjIjoiMmFiMmUxOWJkMDhjZmVhYWIxMGIyYzNmYWIzNTAwMTRhY2RhY2M3NGM4MGUzNzM2OTFkOTliYmI3ODcwN2QzMiJ9', 'laravel_session' => 'eyJpdiI6IkFhcDU3cE9OUWlKaDhYQXBJTDlTbXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiakE4NlZqcVBcL2JVK0RUaGNOUitoVUxMdW00WWdwR091SjNrT3NqcjVBMHNhZ202bG9MaGhFanlMVlUxQVZPOFJiQ0dxNmhxcGtpcHg1SGk4OW5WalwvZz09IiwibWFjIjoiZWViYjM4NTdkZDlmMGJlZGEwYzQwODRlYTE3NjY0YzAwNjZiYzQ2YmE4OGI2ODMxM2MzMjQ2NWRhNTM5MzYzZSJ9') }; public $headers = class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag { protected $headers = array ('host' => array (0 => 'lfs54.dev'), 'connection' => array (0 => 'keep-alive'), 'cache-control' => array (0 => 'max-age=0'), 'upgrade-insecure-requests' => array (0 => '1'), 'user-agent' => array (0 => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'), 'accept' => array (0 => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8'), 'accept-encoding' => array (0 => 'gzip, deflate'), 'accept-language' => array (0 => 'de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ru;q=0.2'), 'cookie' => array (0 => 'XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjFaZkRiSnV1R0ROS3ZaZ1NhRSt1Z2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibks2VUI2OHZ6QzAxOHhEVWk1QjMzUjJwUzB0UGFZSXlLN1k4NmRhME9QYm9ZXC8xdWxlaVZNOU9cL3prM0VVSkMrN0J1N1czYW5vZHZ1WEY0RTdOWnNPQT09IiwibWFjIjoiMmFiMmUxOWJkMDhjZmVhYWIxMGIyYzNmYWIzNTAwMTRhY2RhY2M3NGM4MGUzNzM2OTFkOTliYmI3ODcwN2QzMiJ9; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkFhcDU3cE9OUWlKaDhYQXBJTDlTbXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiakE4NlZqcVBcL2JVK0RUaGNOUitoVUxMdW00WWdwR091SjNrT3NqcjVBMHNhZ202bG9MaGhFanlMVlUxQVZPOFJiQ0dxNmhxcGtpcHg1SGk4OW5WalwvZz09IiwibWFjIjoiZWViYjM4NTdkZDlmMGJlZGEwYzQwODRlYTE3NjY0YzAwNjZiYzQ2YmE4OGI2ODMxM2MzMjQ2NWRhNTM5MzYzZSJ9')); protected $cacheControl = array ('max-age' => '0') }; protected $content = NULL; protected $languages = NULL; protected $charsets = NULL; protected $encodings = NULL; protected $acceptableContentTypes = array (0 => 'text/html', 1 => 'application/xhtml+xml', 2 => 'image/webp', 3 => 'image/apng', 4 => 'application/xml', 5 => '*/*'); protected $pathInfo = NULL; protected $requestUri = NULL; protected $baseUrl = NULL; protected $basePath = NULL; protected $method = NULL; protected $format = NULL; protected $session = NULL; protected $locale = NULL; protected $defaultLocale = 'en'; private ${Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request}:isHostValid = TRUE; private ${Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request}:isClientIpsValid = TRUE; private ${Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request}:isForwardedValid = TRUE }, $e = class InvalidArgumentException { protected $message = 'Attribute [geet] does not exist.'; private ${Exception}:string = ''; protected $code = 0; protected $file = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/projects/laravel/lfs54/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteRegistrar.php'; protected $line = 76; private ${Exception}:trace = array (0 => array ('file' => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/projects/laravel/lfs54/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php', 'line' => 1152, 'function' => 'attribute', 'class' => 'Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteRegistrar', 'type' => '->', 'args' => array (0 => 'geet', 1 => '/')), 1 => array ('file' => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/projects/laravel/lfs54/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php', 'line' => 221, 'function' => '__call', 'class' => 'Illuminate\\Routing\\Router', 'type' => '->', 'args' => array (0 => 'geet', 1 => array (0 => '/', 1 => class Closure { public $this = class Illuminate\Routing\Router { protected $events = class Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher { protected $container = class Illuminate\Foundation\Application { protected $basePath = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/selfstudy/projects/laravel/lfs54'; protected $hasBeenBootstrapped = TRUE; protected $booted = FALSE; protected $bootingCallbacks = array (0 => class Closure { public $static = array ('instance' => class Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider { protected $defer = TRUE; protected $app = ... }); public $this = ... }); protected $bootedCallbacks = array (); protected $terminatingCallbacks = array (); protected $serviceProviders = array (0 => class Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 1 => class Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 2 => class Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 3 => class Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 4 => class Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 5 => class Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 6 => class Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 7 => class Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 8 => class Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FormRequestServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 9 => class Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider { protected $providers = array (0 => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\FormRequestServiceProvider'); protected $instances = array (0 => class Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FormRequestServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }); protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 10 => class Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 11 => class Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 12 => class Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 13 => class Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 14 => class App\Providers\AppServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 15 => class App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider { protected $policies = array ('App\Model' => 'App\\Policies\\ModelPolicy'); protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 16 => class App\Providers\EventServiceProvider { protected $listen = array ('App\Events\Event' => array (0 => 'App\\Listeners\\EventListener')); protected $subscribe = array (); protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 17 => class App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider { protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers'; protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }, 18 => class Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider { protected $defer = TRUE; protected $app = ... }); protected $loadedProviders = array ('Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FormRequestServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider' => TRUE); protected $deferredServices = array ('Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastManager' => 'Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\Factory' => 'Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\Broadcaster' => 'Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher' => 'Illuminate\\Bus\\BusServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher' => 'Illuminate\\Bus\\BusServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\QueueingDispatcher' => 'Illuminate\\Bus\\BusServiceProvider', 'cache' => 'Illuminate\\Cache\\CacheServiceProvider', 'cache.store' => 'Illuminate\\Cache\\CacheServiceProvider', 'memcached.connector' => 'Illuminate\\Cache\\CacheServiceProvider', 'command.cache.clear' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.cache.forget' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.clear-compiled' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.auth.resets.clear' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.config.cache' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.config.clear' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.down' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.environment' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.key.generate' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.migrate' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.migrate.fresh' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.migrate.install' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.migrate.refresh' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.migrate.reset' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.migrate.rollback' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.migrate.status' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.optimize' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.package.discover' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.preset' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.queue.failed' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.queue.flush' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.queue.forget' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.queue.listen' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.queue.restart' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.queue.retry' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.queue.work' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.route.cache' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.route.clear' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.route.list' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.seed' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\ScheduleFinishCommand' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\ScheduleRunCommand' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.storage.link' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.up' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.view.clear' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.app.name' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.auth.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.cache.table' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.console.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.controller.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.event.generate' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.event.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.factory.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.job.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.listener.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.mail.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.middleware.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.migrate.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.model.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.notification.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.notification.table' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.policy.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.provider.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.queue.failed-table' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.queue.table' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.request.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.rule.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.seeder.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.session.table' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.serve' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.test.make' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'command.vendor.publish' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'migrator' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'migration.repository' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'migration.creator' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'composer' => 'Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'mailer' => 'Illuminate\\Mail\\MailServiceProvider', 'swift.mailer' => 'Illuminate\\Mail\\MailServiceProvider', 'swift.transport' => 'Illuminate\\Mail\\MailServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Mail\Markdown' => 'Illuminate\\Mail\\MailServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Pipeline\Hub' => 'Illuminate\\Pipeline\\PipelineServiceProvider', 'queue' => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider', 'queue.worker' => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider', 'queue.listener' => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider', 'queue.failer' => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider', 'queue.connection' => 'Illuminate\\Queue\\QueueServiceProvider', 'redis' => 'Illuminate\\Redis\\RedisServiceProvider', 'redis.connection' => 'Illuminate\\Redis\\RedisServiceProvider', 'auth.password' => 'Illuminate\\Auth\\Passwords\\PasswordResetServiceProvider', 'auth.password.broker' => 'Illuminate\\Auth\\Passwords\\PasswordResetServiceProvider', 'translator' => 'Illuminate\\Translation\\TranslationServiceProvider', 'translation.loader' => 'Illuminate\\Translation\\TranslationServiceProvider', 'validator' => 'Illuminate\\Validation\\ValidationServiceProvider', 'validation.presence' => 'Illuminate\\Validation\\ValidationServiceProvider', 'command.tinker' => 'Laravel\\Tinker\\TinkerServiceProvider'); protected $monologConfigurator = NULL; protected $databasePath = NULL; protected $storagePath = NULL; protected $environmentPath = NULL; protected $environmentFile = '.env'; protected $namespace = NULL; protected $resolved = array ('events' => TRUE, 'router' => TRUE, 'App\Http\Kernel' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions' => TRUE, 'env' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders' => TRUE, 'db.factory' => TRUE, 'db' => TRUE, 'view.engine.resolver' => TRUE, 'files' => TRUE, 'view.finder' => TRUE, 'view' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate' => TRUE, 'url' => TRUE, 'App\Exceptions\Handler' => TRUE, 'Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler' => TRUE, 'log' => TRUE, 'auth' => TRUE, 'hash' => TRUE, 'session' => TRUE, 'session.store' => TRUE, 'cookie' => TRUE); protected $bindings = array ('events' => array ('concrete' => class Closure { public $this = class Illuminate\Events\EventServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }; public $parameter = array ('$app' => '<required>') }, 'shared' => TRUE), 'log' => array ('concrete' => class Closure { public $this = class Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE } }, 'shared' => TRUE), 'router' => array ('concrete' => class Closure { public $this = class Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }; public $parameter = array ('$app' => '<required>') }, 'shared' => TRUE), 'url' => array ('concrete' => class Closure { public $this = class Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }; public $parameter = array ('$app' => '<required>') }, 'shared' => TRUE), 'redirect' => array ('concrete' => class Closure { public $this = class Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider { protected $app = ...; protected $defer = FALSE }; public $parameter = array ('$app' => '<required>') }, 'shared' => TRUE), 'Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface' => array ('concrete' => class Closure
```

On the other hand the Whoops feature seems to work fine. If I provoke an error situation with e. g.:

```
Route::get('/', functtion () {
return view('welcome');
});
```

it works as expected.

Comment: Please could you clear your log file, reload the page so that your php_error.log gets populated again and then give a summary of the issues you are getting as I doubt many people would be comfortable downloading the file.

Comment: I am not going to download a 850 MB file from some external hosting service now to go see what you mean ... Please show a few of the relevant lines from your error log directly inside the question.

Comment: @RossWilson That is what I basically did. Cleared the log file and then ran the use case as described in the description. I also added the first lines of the log file.

Comment: @CBroe The challenge is that I don't know what the relevant lines from the error log are. I see that Laravel floats the php_error.log with messages, but I don't know which are relevant to solve the problem. Therefore I added the first lines of the log file.

Comment: Firstly, delete your vendor folder, run `composer self-update` and then `composer install`. If that fails, make a copy of your composer.lock file and then delete the original (If you're using git and you've committed your `composer.lock` file you won't need to do that). Then delete your vendor  folder again and run `composer install`.

Comment: Thanks to all for your support. Finally, I installed Laravel Homestead and now it works as expected.